# Launching proper version of Eclipse IDE via i3wm

Tags: java, eclipse, i3-wm

So currently I use the gnome desktop and somehow I ended up with 2 versions of eclipse. If I recall correctly, I installed one via the Ubuntu software center and the other from the eclipse website. When I use i3 and launch eclipse the older version of eclipse launches. There is only one version that appears in the dmenu(launcher bar). How can I set it up so i3 will launch the newer version that I need? I've attached a screen shot that will hopefully better illustrate what is going on. The left eclipse with white theme is what launches in i3 and I need the right one with the dark theme to launch. How can I archive this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can have multiple version of eclipse...you need to find out where both of them are installed. My advice...have only one Eclipse and try to have multiple workspaces...

Comment: @Ashu yeah I didn't mean to keep the old version around forgot it was installed until earlier today. Ended up uninstalling all versions of eclipse reinstalling the newest only and now in my dmenu I have `eclipse44` which launches the newest version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to uninstall all versions of eclipse I can't remember the exact commands but basically I did `sudo apt-get purge eclipse*` and then also did `whereis eclipse` and deleted all of the directories it returned. After that I reinstalled eclipse and now when I launch dmenu I have an eclipse44 option that launches the current version of eclipse.